ZIP interpretation
I am looking to improve my knowledge in data analysis and therefore in statistics.
I am interested in sighting rays during underwater diving. I have a dataset that corresponds to nearly 10,000 dives carried out: over 2 years, by different diving clubs, and in several sectors that are spread over 4 islands (the same diving club can carry out several dives).
For each dive carried out, the club provides the location (Island and sector), the date, the time of day, and the number of rays sighted (N_eagle).
I would like to see if there are islands where there are more sight of rays than others. As the data on ray sighting (N_eagle) contains a lot of "0" (almost 95% of the data), I choose a ZIP.
The results obtained are below.

Can you help me interpret the results? I am not sure I understand, especially how to interpret the 2 blocks and how to compare observations between the islands, despite research on internet sites (should I put the results in exponentials to interpret them? how to interpret the negative sign, etc…).
I am also open to all your advice and recommendations (especially in terms of useful internet sites to improve in stats).
Wishing you an excellent day, and thank you so much for your help,
Océane

Briefly, zero-inflated Poisson regression assumes that zeros are created by two processes: i) "true" or excess zeros and ii) sampling zeros (from the Poisson distribution). As an example (from here): Biologists ask visitors of a state park how many fish they caught. Unfortunately, the biologists do not know which visitors fished and which did not. Some visitors did not fish, resulting in "true" or excess zeros. Some of those visitors who did fish, did not catch any fish, resulting in sampling zeros.
The second model is a logistic regression with a logit link for excess zeros ("true" zeros). So you could exponentiate the coefficients to get odds ratios or calculate the predicted probabilities for excess zeros. To give an example: The odds of excess zeros for IleSaint-Martin are $\exp(-2.65) = 0.07$ times lower compared to the odds of the reference category (which is not shown in the output). The predicted probability of excess zeros for IleSaint-Martin is around $0.603$ (plogis(3.06726-2.65040) in R).
The first model is a Poisson regression. Exponentiation the coefficients gives us the changes in expected number of sightings relative to the reference category (for categorical predictors). For example: For IleSaint-Martin, the expected number of sightings is $\exp(-0.748)=0.47$ times lower than for the reference category (not shown in output). The mean number of sightings for IleSaint-Martin is $\exp(0.00425-0.74804)= 0.475$ (this is the estimated mean of the Poisson distribution). For the reference category, the expected number of sightings is roughly $1$.

I believe the reference category here is Anguilla.
